# MOSFET doesn't put out desired voltage

Tags: mosfet

I have an [IRFB7430](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfb7430pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356169bcd1e53) which I want to use to switch 12V. There will be minimal load on the MOSFET, since it is only used to switch a signal. I know it is not its intended use, but it's what I have lying around.

The signal on the Gate is only 5V, which should leave the MOSFET with a higher-than-intended R_DSon, but since I only want to switch a voltage, not a current, I thought it might not be a problem.

However, the output is only around 3.6V, and even if I switch with a 12V signal (which should get the R_DSon to single digit mOhm), I only get 10.5V on the Drain.

I have a 26kOhm pull down resistor on the Gate, and a current limiting resistor of 220 Ohm. Removing either of these did not bring significant changes. +12V is connected to Drain and I am measuring between ground and Source.

I guess there is something in the design of the MOSFET which I don't understand and it is its regular behavior. What am I missing?

Comment: Please post a schematic, words are difficult to interpret, your 3rd and 4th paragraphs appear to contradict each other for guessing the configuration. It sounds like you have it in follower rather than common source mode, which will cause all your problems.

Comment: Are the 12v ground and 5v ground connected, this would cause a problem with measuring the correct voltage.

Comment: You need a P channel device for what you are trying to do not an N channel. For the part you have he gate must be 4V above the source, if the source is 12V you need 16V on the gate.

Comment: As you all could easily guess, I am a newbie to MOSFETs. And now with your splendid help I realise that the graph in the datasheet says V_GS should be at least 6V. I need to do some catching up with things I took for granted, since now they aren't anymore. As: How can I switch a load with a MOSFET at all if I only have a 5V logic level signal. I think I should be able to dig out the answers without straining you guys and girls more than needed. I will come back to you all! Thanks so far!

Comment: *I realise that the graph in the datasheet says V_GS should be at least 6V* You need 6 V for getting a low Rds (resistance between drain and source) value. That doesn't mean the MOSFET does not turn on at all, it does, but with a higher resistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you by any chance trying to use it as a high-side switch?

I believe so - in which case you're actually using it as a source-follower instead of a switch. This is confirmed by your measurements, where Vs = Vg-1.5V approx. It's not switching, but operating in linear mode and dissipating a lot of power, supplying a fairly accurate Vg-1.5V to the load.

You have 3 options:
(1) generate a gate voltage ABOVE the supply (18 to 20V) to switch ON, and 0V to switch off.
(2) use it on the low side of the load with 12V gate voltage. This is the simplest - a conventional low side switch - and offers the best performance.
(3) replace it with a PMOS FET as a high side switch. Then 12V turns it off and 0V turns it on. But it might be difficult to find a PMOS with such a low ON resistance.

Comment: I reckon you are spot on and ya beat me to it +1

Comment: Apparently I am. As explained in the comment to the original question, I am quite new to this, and all I wanted was to 'amplify' the voltage of a 5V logic signal to a 12V signal to get the same  IRFB7430 down to the desired R_DSon. This is a workaround because my housing situation will change before I can get hold of an IRLR8743, which will be the final solution. Thanks for your elaborate answer, I learned a lot through this and it pointed me into the right direction. I am still wondering why there is no easy way to achieve the amplification of a voltage ;)

Comment: Wait what ... are you using a 409 Amp MOSFET as a gate driver????  No... Use any old NMOS or even a bipolar transistor (with a 1K resistor in series with the base) as an inverting amplifier as in Andrew's (nod Andy's) answer, this is Option 2 above. And if you can't invert the logic level input in software (or an inverter gate) simply use a second one to restore the correct polarity. If that's too much work, find a gate driver IC to do the job

Comment: Yeah, exactly, it was a bit of a crazy plan, but I also wanted to understand better what I'm doing for any future projects. I ended up doing option 3 with an IRF9530 which I also had lying around from a lab that has been disbanded. I thus inverted the 12V signal from a low-side switch that was already on the board I get the signals from and thus didn't have to rewrite anything in software. Thanks again, also for the thoughtful comment above!

Answer (score 2):

> +12V is connected to Drain and I am measuring between ground and Source

To turn on a regular N channel MOSFET, the gate voltage has to be higher than the source voltage.

So, if you put 5 volts on the gate, the MOSFET will turn on when the source is at 0 volts for sure. It will still usually turn on when the source is at 1 or 2 volts but is becoming weaker in that the on-resistance is beginning to rise. With 3 or 4 volts on the source, the MOSFET is hardly turned on at all.

This is what I recommend for a 0 volt tied load: -

[image]

See also [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91360/correct-way-to-add-high-side-transistor-to-circuit-with-higher-vcc-than-mcu) SE.EE Q & A

Comment: Just to clarify since kamuro is new to MOSFETs: M2 is an n-channel MOSFET such as you already have. M1 is a p-channel part which you don't currently have (or at least haven't mentioned having). The difference in the two symbols is easy to miss if you don't know to look for it.

Comment: @Andrew good call (for beginners and easily misinterpreted for seasoned veterans).

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is amplify the voltage for a signal from 5 V to 12 V rather than switch power to something on and off then you can do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkcBJo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This has a couple of big drawbacks over Andy aka's answer.

1. It will invert the sense of the signal, a low input will give a high output.
2. With a high output you have a series resistor in line with the signal, depending on what you need to drive this could be a big issue. The lower R1 the less of an issue this is.
3. When a low output you are dumping power through R1/M1. This is both a waste of power and depending on how 'on' M1 is could cause a lot of power loss and heat in M1. The larger R1 is the less of an issue this is.
4. When switching from a low to high output there will be a ramp up time based on R1 and the output capacitance. This may or may not be an issue depending on the load and value of R1.

You can avoid the inverting issue by putting two of these stages in a row. In that situation R1 for the first stage can be nice and large (say 10k) since there is no significant load.

The resistor in the final stage and how practical this approach is depends a lot on the load being driven. Calculate a maximum for R1 based on the expected current draw and maximum acceptable voltage drop at the load and then check if that maximum is too low in terms of acceptable efficiency and M1 power dissipation.

If you look at Andy aka's answer you will notice that it is using this exact circuit to generate the 12V signal needed to drive the gate of the p-channel part.