# Measuring battery voltage, capacitor on drain (nMOSFET switching load)

Tags: mosfet, switching

I've got a schematic to measure a battery voltage using a nMosfet (triggered by a GPIO high level). The voltage is measured at the Probe (see picture).

Can you tell me the purpose of Capacitor C1 on drain and how its value is determined?

[image]

**edit:**

(here's a quick answer before I take more time to check in deep your analysis)

Well yes I forgot to mention:

- the Probe is actually a MCU PIN (nrf52 / 3.3V) so yes to ADC
- the nMOSFET is [NTK3134N](https://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NTK3134N) ([datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NTK3134N-D.PDF))
- the battery is a Lipo (like 3.7 V)

I know putting capacitors like this is to prevent AC and spikes but I wondered if there were other reasons for that.

Comment: There are some potential issues with this circuit that should be explained like, what does the "probe" electrically connect to?

Comment: The probe ought to be an A/D converter.  If it's a voltmeter, then you'd measure the battery directly without a voltage divider.  The purpose of the capacitor is to lower the output impedance seen by the A/D converter.  But there is a bigger problem with this circuit.  It uses a low-side switch.  When the switch is open, the full battery voltage will appear on the A/D converter, which can damage the A/D.  Use a high-side switch, or rethink your approach to measurement of battery voltage.

Comment: I wrote about these issues earlier: [Measure battery voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/39429/7036)

Comment: @JimJim, whenever you ask a question on this site I reckon you should hang around for at least one hour to service comments as per the above. At the moment your question is unclear because you need to supply information in order to get it answered properly.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I don't think it's an issue if the battery is the power supply of the microcontroller.

Comment: @NickAlexeev The cap shown in the circuit has absolutely no function for a DC voltage input. 10pf tells you this only has any potential relevance at RF …. > 1MHz.

Comment: @Andy aka, Ok in the future I'll check for replies right after, because in this forum were're not notified by email whenever a question is added